# Prove that $Decision Tree Complexity$ $\leq$ $(Certificate Complexity)^{2}$

Tags: complexity-theory

I have been trying to understand the following proof but so far no cigars.

**My Understanding:**
For a given function $f$ we can define $C_{1}(f)$ as a $k$-DNF formula where $k$ represents the size of the certificate and where every clause in the formula is a different certificate. Similarly we can define $C_{0}(f)$ as a $k$-CNF formula. I also understand that every 1-certificate intersects every 0-certificate in at least one bit (represented by a literal in the formula) otherwise we would have an input that is consistent with both certificates which is not allowed.

To prove, we want to show that construction of a $Decision Tree$ is bounded by $(Certificate Complexity)^{2}$.

**Proof:**
The proof suggests we can randomly sample from the certificates in the $C_{1}$. Suppose we choose certificate $s$, we can then query all the variables in this clause. If we obtain 1 we are done, else we can "strip-off" from $C_{1}$ anything that is inconsistent with the bits that have been queried. Each term in $C_{1}$ gets its size reduced by at least one. The resulting $C_{1}$ is still such that each pair of clauses has a common literal. This process continues until the value of the function is found or $C_{1}$ is empty.

**Question:**
I cannot picture how one can construct a branch in a Decision Tree from a certificate which has some bits set as non-decided. Moreover, it is confusing to see how the stripping operates in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the proof in more detail. We are given a function $f\colon \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$, and want to design a decision tree for $f$ of depth at most $C_0(f) C_1(f)$. This corresponds to an algorithm which makes at most $C_0(f) C_1(f)$ many queries to the inputs of $f$ and finds out the value of $f$.

The algorithm will maintain a partial assignment $\alpha$, initially empty, which will consist of these values of the input which have already been determined.
It makes $C_0(f)$ iterations of the following form. At the beginning of each iteration, the algorithm checks whether $\alpha$ satisfies some $b$-certificate of $f$ for some $b \in \{0,1\}$ (this is a certificate that certifies that the value of $f$ is $b$), and if so, outputs $b$. Otherwise, it picks an arbitrary¹ $1$-certificate of $f$ which is consistent with $\alpha$. Call that certificate $A$.

The certificate $A$ consists of pairs $(i,b_i)$, where $i \in [n]$ and $b \in \{0,1\}$. Some of the $i$ mentioned in $A$ are in the support of $\alpha$ (the support consists of the indices of variables whose values are assigned by $\alpha$); since we assumed that $A$ is consistent with $\alpha$, in this case $\alpha(i) = b_i$. We ask for the values of the $i$'s in $A$ which are not in the support of $\alpha$, and update $\alpha$ with their values. If all values are consistent with $A$, then we answer $b$, and otherwise we continue to the next iteration, if there is one.

If we have reached the last iteration, we make one last check, whether $\alpha$ satisfies some $b$-certificate for some $b \in \{0,1\}$, answering $b$ in that case. Otherwise, we answer $1$ ("final step").

---

At each iteration, the algorithm makes at most $C_1(f)$ many queries (since the certificate $A$ mentions at most so many variables). Since there are $C_0(f)$ many iterations, it makes at most $C_0(f) C_1(f)$ many queries in total. It remains to argue that it outputs the correct value of $f$. This is clearly the case if it outputs $b$ upon finding a $b$-certificate, so we have to explain why it can answer $1$ at the final step.

Let $x$ be the real input, and suppose that $f(x) = 0$. Choose an arbitrary $0$-certificate $B$ for $x$, which is of size at most $C_0(f)$. At each iteration $t$ of the algorithm, it chooses a $1$-certificate $A$ consistent with $\alpha$ and so with $B$, and asks all involved variables. Since $A$ is a $1$-certificate and $B$ is a $0$-certificate, the two must have some variable $i$ in common such that $A(i) \neq B(i)$, and this variable gets queried at iteration $t$ (it cannot have been queried earlier since $A$ is consistent with $\alpha$). Hence at each iteration, $|\alpha \cap B|$ increases by at least $1$. Consequently, after at most $|B| \leq C_0(f)$ iterations, $\alpha$ will satisfy $B$, and so the algorithm will output $0$, without reaching the final step. It follows that if we have reached the final step then necessarily $f(x) = 1$, and so we can safely return $1$.

---

¹The word *random* has a particular connotation in theoretical computation science, and is not appropriate here.